# On Maven2, how may I call an URL at the end of a (failed or successful) build?

Tags: maven-2, continuous-integration

I've build a [small AppeEngine application](http://build-status.appspot.com/?app_name=myApp) which displays a green or red screen according to an URL call ([/pass](http://build-status.appspot.com/pass?app_name=myApp) or [/fail](http://build-status.appspot.com/fail?app_name=myApp)). That page is refreshed every minute.

The idea is to use a spare computer to display that build status page and set a [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Integration) tool (TeamCity in my case) which will call the /pass or /fail URL at the end of each maven 2 build.

So, how am I able to make maven 2 call an URL at the end of a build ([/pass](http://build-status.appspot.com/pass?app_name=myApp) or [/fail](http://build-status.appspot.com/fail?app_name=myApp))?

I'm thinking about a Maven 2 plugin but is it possible for a plugin to be called at the end of the build (and get the build status)?

Comment: I just saw the maven Notifier class (http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Notifier.html) but does somebody know how to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use antrun from maven in the "install" phase to check for the presence or absence of a file and then execute httpclient (or the equivalent) based on that. Or you could write a wrapper that calls maven and then calls curl.

Comment: Yes, thanks. By the way, I've found that the simple way to call an URL in Java seems to be `new URL('http://yoururl').openStream();`. Notice that I'm not looking for any kind of response.

Answer (score 1):

The [status monitor plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Status+Monitor+Plugin) from Hudson does exactly what you want.
It can even monitor multiple jobs instead of just one.

Comment: Indeed, that's good to know. However, we're using TeamCity and won't change our CI tool any soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think another way is to build a custom notifier for TeamCity, like the [Nabaztag Notifier](http://code.google.com/p/buildbunny/wiki/CreateTeamcityNotifier).

Update: Ok, I just began a custom TeamCity notifier on google code : [buildstatusnotifier](http://code.google.com/p/buildstatusnotifier/). It's so simple to build... :)

Here's the main class, [WebNotifier](http://code.google.com/p/buildstatusnotifier/source/browse/trunk/build-status/src/main/java/org/buildstatus/WebNotifier.java).